# Time from Naples to the NAP airport

Tags: airport-transfer

How long does it take to get from Naples to the Naples airport (NAP) by taxi? I will be traveling early morning on a week day

Answer (score 1):

20 to 30 minutes from the main train station, 30 to 60 minutes (depending on traffic) from Mergellina.